# Fetch component details from Tridion using dd4t api failed and throwing Exception " <Content xmlns=''> was not expected. " in C#

Tags: web8, content-delivery, dd4t, sdl-tridion, content-manager

We are Using DD4T.ContentModel for Retrieving Component info and using dynamic publication resolving method as we handle multiple sites.

Here we are trying to get the component details using componentFactory.getComponent() from a publication that is not a default publication of our site.
If I try to fetch a component from the default publication then I am getting a response but for other publications, it is throwing below exception.

**Need a solution to resolve this error and a way to fetch components from other publications.**

Server Error in '/' Application.
 was not expected.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

Stack trace :

> [InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.]
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read40_Component()
> +165    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +172
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).]
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +819
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader
> textReader) +157
> DD4T.Serialization.XmlSerializerService.Deserialize(String input) in
> C:\projects\dd4t-model\source\DD4T.Serialization\XmlSerializerService.cs:104
> DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation&
> cp, String componentUri, String templateUri) in
> C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\ComponentPresentationFactory.cs:194
> DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation(String
> componentUri, String templateUri) in
> C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\ComponentPresentationFactory.cs:82
> DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.GetComponent(String componentUri,
> String templateUri) in
> C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\ComponentFactory.cs:96

Comment: It looks like you are trying to consume a page which is not published with a DD4T template. Can you preview the page in Tridion and check if the output is valid JSON?

Comment: I have published the component and I previewed the component it is showing in xml Format and the component template used is XMLGenerator_CT.

Comment: Are you using SI4T and, if so, is the SI4T Deployer Extension properly installed?  SI4T TBBs add markup to the rendered output which should be removed again by the SI4T Deployer Extension, otherwise it will cause parsing errors in the Web App.